# Netbeans javascript indents brackets too much

Tags: javascript, netbeans, tabs, indentation

If I type the following javascript in Netbeans...

```
if (foo) [enter] { [enter] dostuff();
```

I get:

```
if (foo)
    {
        dostuff();
    }
```

which is just silly. Is there any way to get the correct result:?

```
if (foo)
{
    dostuff();
}
```

Edit: Apparently this is [a bug that was supposedly fixed years ago](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=182420).

Comment: Don't know the answer, but here's a tip: if you like your opening brackets in the next line, never do that when returning an object from a function, or js will return undefined instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl + Shift + f it is for formatting code automatically by the IDE

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently an open bug with Javascript and NetBeans as of 4/2/2013: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=182420